# ACTIVITI - async serviceTask executed after process end event

Tags: java, activiti

We encountered several cases when serviceTasks are executed AFTER reaching process end event.

One example from the `ACT_HI_ACTINST` table looks like this (line numbers column "L#" added manually):

```
SELECT
   EXECUTION_ID_,
   PROC_INST_ID_,
   ACT_ID_,
   ACT_TYPE_,
   START_TIME_,
   END_TIME_
FROM ACT_HI_ACTINST
WHERE PROC_INST_ID_ =
  '9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09'
ORDER BY
   START_TIME_;

EXECUTION_ID_                           PROC_INST_ID_                           L#  ACT_ID_                         ACT_TYPE_                   START_TIME_             END_TIME_          
====================================    ====================================    === ============================    ========================    ===================     ===================
9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09     1. startevent1                     startEvent                  2016-12-31 00:35:06     2016-12-31 00:35:06
9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09     2. lockOrder                       serviceTask                 2016-12-31 00:35:06     2016-12-31 00:35:06
9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09     3. processingOrderStatus           serviceTask                 2016-12-31 00:35:06     2016-12-31 00:35:06
989cb4b1-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09     4. subprocess1                     subProcess                  2016-12-31 00:35:06     2016-12-31 00:37:18
989e8977-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09     5. startevent2                     startEvent                  2016-12-31 00:35:06     2016-12-31 00:35:06
989e8977-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09     6. prepareContractContext          serviceTask                 2016-12-31 00:35:07     2016-12-31 00:35:07
989e8977-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09     7. processingContractStatus        serviceTask                 2016-12-31 00:35:08     2016-12-31 00:35:09
989e8977-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09     8. createSsoAccount                serviceTask                 2016-12-31 00:35:09     2016-12-31 00:35:09
989e8977-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09     9. exclusivegateway1               exclusiveGateway            2016-12-31 00:35:09     2016-12-31 00:35:09
989e8977-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    10. exclusivegateway2               exclusiveGateway            2016-12-31 00:35:09     2016-12-31 00:35:09
989e8977-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    11. modifyParty                     serviceTask                 2016-12-31 00:35:10     2016-12-31 00:35:26
a44b1fb0-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    12. timerintermediatecatchevent1    intermediateTimer           2016-12-31 00:35:26     2016-12-31 00:37:30
989e8977-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    13. createNotification              serviceTask                 2016-12-31 00:37:17     2016-12-31 00:37:17
989e8977-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    14. closedContractStatus            serviceTask                 2016-12-31 00:37:18     2016-12-31 00:37:18
989e8977-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    15. endevent1                       endEvent                    2016-12-31 00:37:18     2016-12-31 00:37:18
9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    16. registerClosedOrderEvent        serviceTask                 2016-12-31 00:37:19     2016-12-31 00:37:19
9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    17. closedOrderStatus               serviceTask                 2016-12-31 00:37:19     2016-12-31 00:37:19
9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    18. endevent2                       endEvent                    2016-12-31 00:37:19     2016-12-31 00:37:19
989e8977-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    19. modifyService                   serviceTask                 2016-12-31 00:37:30     2016-12-31 00:37:31
eeec32ad-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    9841ea77-cee8-11e6-b457-005056aa6e09    20. waitingForModifyService         intermediateMessageCatch    2016-12-31 00:37:31     2016-12-31 00:37:17
```

[image: Task flow labeled with line numbers from history table]

Now `endEvent2` (line 18) is a process end event and after its completion another task is executed (this `modifyService` (line 19) task should be executed right after `timerintermediatecatchevent1` (line 12) and in most cases is).

We are using Activiti only as a processing engine of our Spring application. There are 5 instances of application connected to the same DB.

What can cause such behavior? We are observing it regularly and this is very dangerous for our business processes. As a hint - unordered tasks were executed on different machines.

Also we tuned settings of async executor engine - code snippet with its settings below:

```
asyncExecutor.setDefaultAsyncJobAcquireWaitTimeInMillis(1000);
asyncExecutor.setDefaultTimerJobAcquireWaitTimeInMillis(5 * 1000);
asyncExecutor.setMaxAsyncJobsDuePerAcquisition(10);
asyncExecutor.setMaxTimerJobsPerAcquisition(10);
asyncExecutor.setAsyncJobLockTimeInMillis(10 * 60 * 1000);
asyncExecutor.setTimerLockTimeInMillis(10 * 60 * 1000);
```

Activiti version: 5.20.0

Any kind of help or hint would be really appreciated.

#### Further reading

- Crosspost on Alfresco forums: https://community.alfresco.com/message/805537-servicetask-executed-after-process-end-event

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue in the jUnit test? (template https://github.com/Activiti/activiti-unit-test-template)

Comment: I didn't try - I was wondering can anyone experienced similar problem. More detailed discussion is placed here: https://community.alfresco.com/message/805537-servicetask-executed-after-process-end-event

It is impossible for me to write test basing on my real process, because it's depending on production data. If it's necessary I would try to provide such test, but it won't be 1:1 representation of my process.

Maybe you have some hint what can cause the problem? Is this rather problem with my process definitions or it's engine fault?

Comment: For the last line the end time is 14 seconds BEFORE start time. Is this a typo?